# 3D car models freely available

Tags: 3d

I enjoy messing around with 3DS Max, and I've always had my way without too many tutorials, as I do pretty much everything in modelling by intuition, and use tutorials for things like effects, materials, and etc.

There's one thing that, despite having attempted more than one, I haven't gotten any close to an even cartunistic version of: A car.

Maybe it's because I don't know how structurally detailed a 3D car model has to be, or I just don't have a clue about how sectioned the outer surfaces can be, but I always end up with this unmanageable model when I try creating a 3D car from imagination.

So I guess I will have to learn by doing what I do best to learn: get a couple of good complete ones, and break them down, studying them.

It would be interesting if I could have 3D models of the cars I have access to (physically), as I'd be able to check it by myself, and compare how the creator has translated each part to a 3d object.

Can you provide me with a link or something to which I can have access to a large number of 3D car models for studying purposes ?

Thank you!

Comment: Questions about anything 3D is really only limited to composition as it pertains to design. Technical questions are off-topic.

Comment: There is a proposal for CG Artists in Area 51 that will answer questions like this. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38889/cg-artists?referrer=HhJgXPk4zFcAw7hjn5MhOA2

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of websites that offer 3D models - http://www.3dxtras.com/ being a perfect example.

As they are free they are generally of a lower standard because it's community driven instead of quality and price driven, however some will surprise you.

A quick google search for Free 3D Model Car brought up this: http://www.carbodydesign.com/download/3d-models/

Not sure how useful this is for you though.

Here's a website that offers linkage to 60 other 3D Model Websites http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/60-excellent-free-3d-model-websites/

Answer (score 0):

I would try to find a tutorial book with a chapter involving the kind of model you're after. Most of them seem to have the sample model files freely available on a website (in case you lose the included CD).